# Http header use with asp.net/html and Signalr

Tags: oauth, signalr, jwt

I wanted to use http headers to transport a security token with assertions from a login to Signalr (so to add user into group via claims). Can I maintain something like an OAth or JWT in the header of the user request after login to the Signalr hub? I would maintain the token in header for the length of the users interaction.

Thanks